# Are Muslims allowed to eat boars?

Tags: halal-haram, food, meat, pork

It is clear that it is haram to eat pork. However, is it permissible to eat [wild boars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_boar) or to use products derived from them (boar bristle brushes)? I ask this because both pigs and boars belong to the biological family *Suidae* and are closely related.

Comment: This is a good question but the accepted answer and the other upvoted answers, even though upvoted and accepted (one), do not provide really solid answers. See my comments to each answer. You may ask, "well what is your answer?". My answer is: "I don't know".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> He has forbidden you only the Maitah (dead animals), and blood, and the flesh of swine, and that which is slaughtered as a sacrifice for others than God (or has been slaughtered for idols). But if one is forced by necessity, without wilful disobedience, nor transgressing due limits, then there is no sin on him. Truly, God is Oft-forgiving Most Merciful. [2:173]

Here, it is said that swine is prohibited, and cannot be eaten unless under special circumstances. Well, swine is actually [the genus *Sus*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig). Scientifically, both the [wild boar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_boar), and the [domestic pig (pork)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pork) fall under this genus.

Based on this information, *Muslims cannot eat boar.*

Comment: good answer, but should be expanded to include the second part of the question (i.e., boar-bristle brushes)

Comment: @goldPseudo I answered what I could. :-)

Comment: Can you provide any proof that a scientific reason holds enough grounds to use it as reasoning for a Muslim to make a final conclusion between haram and halal?

Answer (score 6):

According to [Jafari Fiqh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ja'fari_jurisprudence) the meat of boars is Haram (forbidden) but it is not Najis.
Products made of its hair like brush are allowed to be used.

---

Ref:

By online Answering from [Official website of Grand Ayatollah Makarem Shirazi](http://makarem.ir/websites/english/).

Comment: I made also add that many Suni that the skin is allowed as long as it is dries, as mentioned by the Prophet PBUH.

Answer (score 4):

As Dynamic provided the Ayah:

> He has forbidden you only the Maitah (dead animals), and blood, and
>   the flesh of swine, and that which is slaughtered as a sacrifice for
>   others than God (or has been slaughtered for idols). But if one is
>   forced by necessity, without wilful disobedience, nor transgressing
>   due limits, then there is no sin on him. Truly, God is Oft-forgiving
>   Most Merciful. [2:173]

It is strictly forbidden, except for under certain circumstances as has been said.  Those circumstances are like starving to death, if you must eat and there is really no choice than to eat boar/pig then it is okay, in the Hanafi school it is said to just eat enough to keep you alive, don't eat like you would eat an apple.  If you have an apple than you would eat the whole thing, but lets say that the apple is haraam, or it is boar, you would only take a bite that will keep you alive.

It is forbidden to use any product derived from pigs or boars, the Ayah is the proof, The pig/swine is a filthy animal both inside and out.

Comment: -1 Last statement is not backed by any proof. The Ayah speaks about eating pork, not using it.

Answer (score 0):

I am a zoologist and would like to interject a different answer from a purely scientific angle. Swine (*Sus domesticus*) is a species of domesticated pig in the Sus genus.  Wild boar (*Sus scrofa*) are in the same genus however they are undomesticated, and as their name suggests they live in the wild.  Boar are closely related to domestic pigs (*Sus scrofa* is the ancestor of *Sus domesticus* just like wolves are the ancestors of dogs) however wild boar are a different species to domestic pigs.  As posted previously the Koran explicitly states that swine is forbidden.  Wild boar is not considered swine.  Taking this into account I suppose a Muslim could technically eat any species in the Sus genus except *Sus domesticus* (swine) and still not violate any of the Koranic verses.  It comes down to personal opinion and choice.  If you are Muslim and want to eat pork, then there are several other species similar to pigs that are not considered swine, learn to think for yourself and evaluate the evidence/information carefully!

You can check the taxonomic details on the wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domestic_pig

Comment: The info you provide is correct but scholars reached to the conclusion that from this verse it is also concluded that the whole family is forbidden.

Answer (score -1):

(Comment actually). Eating the meat of swine or pig, has been prohibited to the sons of Israel, it is also prohibited to the sons of Ishmael and the last prophet or messenger of God has also prohibited it to the Muslims, and if we are truly believers of Allah, we should comply without complaint. Even Essa (allayhis sallam) stated that he did not come to destroy the law and the (words of) the prophets. Therefore there should be no reason to ignore their words. Scientifically, we have already been told of its (meat) unhealthy state.

Comment: Where does it say that scientifically? Can you provide evidence? Can you also provide evidence that a scientific reasoning holds ground for a Muslim to obey?

Answer (score -2):

It is clear that everything of the swine is forbidden. The Prophet (sal) forbade using any part of it, including the so called "dried" skin.As for" Ronnie's" answer.......its clear he is ignorant of Islam.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. The "Answer section" is meant to primarily address the original post and focus on answering it, with an well elaborated answer in your own words and with claims supported by evidences (See [answer]). Also commenting on other peoples answers should be done in a constructive manner (see our [be nice policy](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)).